# How can I tap the Toggle under a View in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

There are two views (Toggle and Button) under a view (Rectangle):

```
struct ContentView: View {
        @State var val = false
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Control penetration")
                        .font(.title)
                    
                    Toggle(isOn: $val){EmptyView()}
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Yes! Clicked!")
                    }){
                        Text("Can you click me???")
                    }
                    
                }
                .padding()
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green.opacity(0.2))
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

I use allowsHitTesting() to make the click penetrate to the bottom.

But only the Button can respond to click, the Toggle can not!

What's wrong with it? How can I make the Toggle respond click too? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible workaround - give it explicit tap gesture handler. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
Toggle(isOn: $val){EmptyView()}
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation { val.toggle() }
    }
```

Comment: yes! It's worked! But If I replace Toggle with Slider, it won’t work.so this is not a fundamental solution