# SwiftUI solution to disable hit testing

Tags: swiftui

When using the following layout, the Rectangle still receives touch events stopping the underlying content or scroll view from receiving interaction. I believe this might be a SwiftUI bug?

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    Color.blue
    
    ScrollView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Text")
            Text("Text")
            Button()
        }
    }
    Rectangle()
        .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.red, .clear]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top))
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 150)
        .allowsHitTesting(false)
}
```

Has anyone found a work around for this?

Comment: It works, if you place a button under gradient (and make it half transparent) then button action works. But drag gesture for scrollview is blocked, however this is not about "hit"-testing.

Comment: @Asperi, is there a way of not blocking the scroll view?

Comment: @Asperi Also it appears buttons are tappable, but toggles cannot be toggled?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63750285/12299030